# Allow URL access, disallow subdirectory access

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a second website stored in the root of my main website. It's a subdomain with its own URL

I want users to access the second website via a URL eg

```
 www.mysecondwebsite.com
```

but not via the first website eg

```
 www.myfirstwebsite.com/mysecondwebsite
```

Can this be done via .htaccess? If so where do I put the .htaccess file: in the root of the main site or the root of the subdirectory/domain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the htaccess file in your `mysecondwebsite` folder, add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mysecondwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

You can also replace `R=404` with `F` if you'd rather return a 403 Forbidden.